# Speed of Ram via serial Number

Tags: macos, memory, mac-mini, serial-number

Is it possible to tell the speed of R.A.M of a Mac Mini by the serial number, and if so where would one do that? I need to know whether or not a Mac Mini is specifically Pc3-8500 through the serial number alone.

Comment: Which Mac Mini? All but the most recent ones have user-replacable RAM or are you just interested in the overall speed qualification and not specifics about installed memory?

Comment: basically just if it is possible to see the RAM specs via Serial Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get any Mac's product manual from

- https://support.apple.com/manuals/C02PRT1XGCN3

Just add your serial number instead of the sample one I provided.

Comment: No that is one I did not know a + for that.